# Specify particular Rakudo version in Raku module

Tags: raku, rakudo

Today, I learned in IRC chat that

```
my @a = [9, 4, 3, 2, 7];
say @a.sort(:k) # (3 2 1 4 0)
```

is available since Rakudo 2023.08. I want my module to use this feature. Is there **inbuilt** mechanism to specify this in module, may be by modifying META6.json ?

Like if the Rakudo is earlier than 2023.08, *fail* the installation of module.

What I know is we can specify `6.c`, `6.d`, `6.e` e.g:

```
"raku": "6.d"
```

in **META6.json** file. This however does not address the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly current Raku does not have an inbuilt mechanism to control the VM version such as 2023.08 (eg. via META6.json) below the level of major raku release such as 6.d.

I suggest (and would support) this as a new feature request. In the meantime, here is a rough and ready workaround:

```
die "must be raku v2023.08 or greater" 
unless $*VM.version ~~ v2023.08+;
```

^^ put this in your test if you want installation to fail

- https://docs.raku.org/type/Version
- https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#$*VM

Comment: You can fail a test instead of causing the test file to exit

Comment: @librasteve Yes that's a workaround (I suppose not a good practice though). I was looking for **inbuilt** mechanism. If it can be specified in **META6** file in some way, that would be better. As language adds new features, this seems like a *must have* feature apart from specifications: 6.c,6.d...

Comment: @librasteve Another possible solution is to put your code in **`Build.rakumod`** in root directory of the module. It won't install before going to tests. But I was looking for inbuilt mechanism to address this *not so uncommon* problem.

Comment: @Coke - I know that you can fail an individual test instead, and perhaps slide a ```warn``` into the text flow before the generic ```try with --force-test``` alternative, but since @suman say s ```fail the installation of module``` I felt that you would want it to fail big with an error message so that the user knows to upgrade their raku

Comment: @suman - in my research (which admittedly, was not exhaustive) there is no META6.json attribute for the VM version (such as 2023.08) and the ```use 6.d;``` method does not reflect these incremental non breaking improvements that get shipped from time to time. I am happy to be proven wrong, but in the absence of that, you are in feature request territory (which I would support). I have edited my answer to state this - if you accept then it means that others that come this way in future will get a better understanding of the status and a viable workaround at least.

Comment: @librasteve I agree there is no attribute to specify VM version in META6 file, but for `6.d`, I think a line `"raku": "6.d"` in META file does that.

Comment: You can also fail in the Build.rakumod file - see https://github.com/Raku/doc/blob/main/Build.rakumod for an example that dies all the time, can be modified to include any error message on any condition.